# Intensity in RGB image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have RGB image of vessels. To distinguish two vessel type (Artery and vein), I need to calculate the intensity in RGB image in circular ROI. Vein (V) is dark red in colour while artery is light red in colour. Instead of calculating intensity in different channel (R , G and B) , Is it possible to calculate intensity in RGB image?

I have done intensity calculation  in only one channel (say green channel) in following manner:

```
 image=imread('vesselAV.jpg');
 t = 0:pi/20:2*pi;

 xi = R0*cos(t)+x; % where x , y are coordinate of centre of circular roi   
                         % (marked  in image)
yi = R0*sin(t)+y;

g=image(:,:,2);

roimask = poly2mask(double(xi),double(yi), size(g,1),size(g,2));

pr_gc = find(roimask);

Intensity_green_roi_V =(g(pr_gc)); % intensity in roi for vein
```

similarly I have calculated Intensity in roi for artery....

But How can I calculate the intensity value in RGB image...?????

Thanks

Comment: Convert to HSV and then only look at the V channel perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you want to convert the pixels to grayscale values to get a single intensity. There are a number of different ways, and [this blog lists three of them](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) so I suggest you read that.  However if you just want something quick, I would be inclined to simply convert the whole image to grayscale and use that value:

```
grayIm = rgb2gray(image);
```

The `rgb2gray` function uses the luminosity of the image (the V in HSV), which is the third example in the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question.  So forgive me if this answer is off.  At pixel i,j, image(i,j,:) is a three element vector, with intensity values for the three channels R, G, and B.  If you don't want to work with a 3 element vector, then I would recommend using the R intensity, as the largest deviation appears to occur there.  i.e. work with image(:,:,1).

If you're looking for the 3 dimensional "typical" intensity, then generally, you compute a mean over the pixels of interest.

Say, `mask` is your region of interest represented as a 2D matrix of 1's and 0's, then this will compute the average 3D intensity in your region of interest:

```
sum(sum(double(image).*repmat(mask,[1 1 3]),2),1) / sum(reshape(mask,[],1)))
```

Now, you can use this mean intensity and some euclidean distance metrics to determine if the desired pixels are contained in your "vein" definitions.

There are lots of other ways to attack this segmentation problem, this appears to be the one you're asking about however.